# Why this cookie doesn't work?

Tags: php, cookies, mobile

My site have a full version and a mobile version. When type the URL, the `index.php` will detect user's client to direct to full version or mobile version. This works fine. Users from desktop client can also switch to mobile version. But I have trouble for users from mobile client switching to full version. The codes are here:

```
// index.php
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('...',substr($useragent,0,4))) {
  $type = 'mobile';
} else {
  $type = 'full';
}
if ($type == 'mobile' and $_COOKIE['switch'] != 'full') {
  header ('Location: m/');
} else {
  include './front.html.php';
}
?>

// m/switch.php  page when user click
<?php
setcookie('switch', 'full', time() + 60);
header('Location: ../');
?>
```

I have also reversed the order of `setcookie` and `header`, but still doesn't work.

<strike>Is it possible cookie is forbidden in mobile device?</strike>

*** Update ***

I added a `$type = 'mobile';` before the condition, so that no matter what client, it is assumed to be mobile. Then I used Chrome from my laptop to test, and the cookies are definitely enabled. It goes to mobile version (ok), but click `switch` still does not go to full version. So it is problem of the cookie itself.

Comment: Yes, depending on the mobile device cookies and / or javascript will not work.
Can you tell me what phone you are using to test this?

Comment: Cookies are not forbidden by default, it could be that your mobile browser is not accepting cookies at the moment, you can just enable this.

Comment: use an actual path in the switch.php header like `header('Location: /index.php');`

Comment: Virtually any mobile device handles cookies, and JS is in most.

Comment: @Rufinus doesn't work. Is there something wrong with the use of `setcookie`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the path of the cookie

```
setcookie('switch', 'full', time() + 60, '/');
```

From the manual we can know

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

In you example the script `switch.php` will set the cookie in the path `/m/` (default value is the current directory).
However your `index.php` was trying to read cookie form `/`, thus the redirection will fail.